# Prove that the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x-1}dx$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

How do you show that \begin{equation*}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\end{equation*} exists? (without using the $\text{Li}_2$ function etc. - I just want to show existence, not calculate the value).

Comment: Hints: (a) $\frac{\log x}{x-1}$ extends to a continuous function at $x=1$; (b) $|x-1| \ge \frac12$ for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.

Comment: @GregMartin: Can you please explain how to prove formally that statement? Thanks!

Comment: @ZaWarudo Greg Martin's (a) follows from the fact that $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\log x}{x-1} = 1$ by L'Hôpital's rule, and (b) is obvious. Then we deduce that the integrand is bounded above by $\frac{\log x}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} = 2\log x$, and $\int_{0}^{1}(2\log x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ can easily be shown to exist.

Comment: @Prasiortle: Thanks for your answer, but my doubt was (b). It is intuitively obvious to me too, but I think that some work with the $\delta$ in the limit definition has to be done to make it rigorous, and I was interested in that.

Comment: (b) simply says $\left\lvert x-1\right\rvert \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $x$ near zero, and indeed, $\left\lvert x-1\right\rvert \geq \frac{1}{2} \iff x - 1 \geq \frac{1}{2} \text{ or } x - 1 \leq -\frac{1}{2} \iff x \geq \frac{3}{2} \text{ or } x \leq \frac{1}{2}$. When $x$ is near zero, it will certainly be less than $\frac{1}{2}$, so the statement is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\log x}{x-1}$ can be extended to a continuous function in 1 as $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x}{x-1} = 1$ so no problem for convergence of integral there.
For $x \to 0^+$ it's easy to show that $\frac{\log x}{x-1} < 2 \log x$ in a right neighbourhood of $0$ and $ 2 \log x$ converges, so the given integral is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

With $y:=1-x$ the integral becomes $-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}dy=\int_0^1\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{y^{n-1}}{n}dy=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges by comparison with $\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}$. (In particular, the monotone convergence theorem justifies the sum-integral exchange.) I contend that's a proof of convergence that doesn't compute the integral. If you evaluate its value, [I can't be held responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Note

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}dx
 &=  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x} {x^2-1}dx+ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log x}{x^2-1}dx\\
 &
= \frac12 \int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{\log x}{x-1}- \frac{\log x}{x+1} \right)dx + \frac14\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log t}{t-1}dt\\
\end{align*}

which leads to

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}dx=-2 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x+1}dx< -2 \int_{0}^{1}\log x dx=2
$$

Thus, the integral is bounded, hence existing.

Comment: I don't understand what happens to the $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\log x}{x^2-1} \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ term - why does it just disappear?